# Show that $p_{ii}^{(k+l)}\geqslant p_{ij}^{(k)}\cdot p_{ji}^{(\ell)}$

Tags: proof-verification, markov-chains

> > Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ be an irreducible Markov chain with state space $E$ and Transition Matrix $P=(p_{ij})_{i,j\in E}$. Set
> >     $$
> > p_{ii}^{(n)}=\mathbb{P}(X_n=i|X_0=i)=:\mathbb{P}_i(X_n=i).
> > $$
> >     Let $i,j\in E$ with $i\neq j$. By irreducibility there exist $k,\ell\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p_{ij}^{(k)}>0$ and $p_{ji}^{(\ell)}>0$. Show that
> >     $$
> > p_{ii}^{(k+l)}\geqslant p_{ij}^{(k)}\cdot p_{ji}^{(\ell)}>0.
> > $$

My idea is to use the **Chapman-Kolmogorov Equation** which is as follows:

> > Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ be a Markov chain with state space $E$ and Transition Matrix $P$. Let $k<m<n$. Then for all $i,j\in E$ it is
> >     $$
> > \mathbb{P}(X_n=j|X_k=i)=\sum_{y\in E}\mathbb{P}(X_n=j|X_m=y)\cdot\mathbb{P}(X_m=y|X_k=i).
> > $$

*Now to my proof:*

Without loss of generality let $k<\ell$. Using the Markov property and the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation, it is

\begin{align}
p_{ii}^{(k+\ell)}&=\mathbb{P}_i(X_{k+\ell}=i)\\
&=\sum_{a\in E}\sum_{b\in E}\mathbb{P}_i(X_{k+\ell}=i,X_k=a,X_{\ell}=b)\\
&=\sum_{a\in E}\sum_{b\in E}\mathbb{P}_i(X_{k+\ell}=i|X_k=a,X_{\ell}=b)\cdot\mathbb{P}_i(X_k=a,X_{\ell}=b)\\
&=\sum_{a\in E}\sum_{b\in E}\mathbb{P}_i(X_{k+\ell}=i|X_{\ell}=b)\cdot \mathbb{P}_i(X_{\ell}=b|X_k=a)\cdot\mathbb{P}_i(X_k=a)\\
&=\sum_{a\in E}\mathbb{P}_i(X_{k+\ell}=i|X_k=a)\cdot\mathbb{P}_i(X_k=a)\\
&=\sum_{a\in E}p_{ia}^{(k)}\cdot p_{ai}^{(\ell)}\\
&\geqslant p_{ij}^{(k)}\cdot p_{ji}^{(\ell)}.
\end{align}

It would be great if you could tell me if my proof is ok.

Thank you and with greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct.

Alternative argumentation: For

$$P^n := \underbrace{P \cdots P}_{\text{$n$ times}} = (p_{ij}^{(n)})_{i,j \in E}, \qquad n \in \mathbb{N},$$

we have $P^{k+l} = P^k \cdot P^l$. Therefore,

$$p^{(k+l)}_{ii} = \sum_{j \in E} p_{ij}^{(k)} p_{ji}^{(l)} \geq p_{i j_0}^{(k)} p_{j_0 i}^{(l)}$$

for any fixed $j_0 \in E$.